# Get element in embedded page <object> by jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a webpage which has an external webpage loaded in an < object > tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    var t = $("#wrapper").html();
    alert(t);
});
</script>
  </head>
     <body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <object id="embSite" type="text/html" data="includediv.htm" width="100%"  height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
 </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

my includediv.htm has the following content:

```
 <div id="includedDiv">This is the included page</div>
```

In my alert I get just the html of the object tag but not the content of includediv.htm. How can I access those elements from the external page?

Comment: check browsers console (F12) for errors. do you receive a *Permission Denied* ?

Comment: No there are no error messages in de Console (using Chrome)

Answer (score 3):

You can find element in the html content you get like below:

```
  $.get(yourlink, function (data) {
    var fullHTML = data;
    $(fullHTML).find('#includedDiv').html();
}
```